# How to merge Facebook Pages with new subscription-enabled Profiles?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-subscriptions

Since [Facebook released](https://blog.facebook.com/blog.php?post=10150280039742131) the subscription based profiles, I assume this would be recommended way to handle your identity instead of creating a separate Facebook Page for content heavy info as Mark did here

https://www.facebook.com/zuck <- Profile
https://www.facebook.com/markzuckerberg <- "Public Figure" Facebook Page

Is there a way to have the best of both worlds?

From what I understand, subscribe allows for any post set to public to be seen. Though it still feels this will "spam" current friends, it one were to do all their sharing within their Facebook profile only.

My current idea would be to have all friends on a list, I hide them with Custom Privacy, then set the public to public. Meaning that these friends would have to subscribe to get the updates. Though this is all in theory, I have not found a way to do this and I have fallen back to the "zuck" method for now.

[image: Publish to Public]

**Update**
So Mark and I think the same... you know why?

https://www.facebook.com/markzuckerberg now redirects to https://www.facebook.com/zuck

I am guessing this feature is only available to him. Or is this a hint that users should use their Facebook profiles and not "Public Figure" Facebook Pages?

Comment: For what it's worth, a lot of people are asking this question. No fewer that two tech podcasts wondered much the same thing immediately following Fbook's announcement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it's not possible, its the same as when you merge a [profile to a page](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=19691&tq)
and all of your info gets lost, while only keeping the contact in some cases.